# Bootstrap 4 carousel: make the slides at the left and right of the active slide visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am working on a full-screen Bootstrap 4 carousel. The slides contain not images, but *videos* and captions.

My intention is to lay the captions of the slides at the left and right of the active slide, over the slider controls, to give the impression that the captions are used *as controls*. An illustration of the desired effect can be seen below:

[image]

To achieve my goal, I have written the following code:

```js
var slider = $('#full_slider');
var slidesNo = slider.find('.carousel-item').length;

var fullSliderNavigation = function(index) {
  var slide = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index);
  if (slide.is(':first-child')) {
    var slidePrev = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(slidesNo - 1);
  } else {
    var slidePrev = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index - 1);
  }

  if (slide.is(':last-child')) {
    var slideNext = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(0);
  } else {
    var slideNext = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index + 1);
  }

  $('.carousel-item').removeClass('right-slide left-slide');
  slideNext.addClass('right-slide');
  slidePrev.addClass('left-slide');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  fullSliderNavigation(0);

  $(slider).on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
    var index = $(event.relatedTarget).index();
    fullSliderNavigation(index);
  });
});
```

```css
#full_slider {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
#full_slider .carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#full_slider .carousel-item .video-caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transition: all 500ms;
  transform: translateX(-60px) translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  color: #fff;
}
#full_slider .carousel-item .allcases {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: none;
}
#full_slider .carousel-item .allcases a {
  color: #fff;
}
#full_slider .carousel-item.active,
#full_slider .carousel-item-left,
#full_slider .carousel-item-right {
  display: flex !important;
}
#full_slider .carousel-item.active .video-caption {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
#full_slider .carousel-item.active .allcases {
  display: block;
}
#full_slider video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
#full_slider h3 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
}
#full_slider .control {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div id="full_slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/flamenco.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/protest.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Falling in love</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Coffe</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="control text-left"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="control text-left"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The (obvious) problem here is that the slides at the left and right of the active slide have `display: none;` so *their captions are not visible*.

By default, the Bootstrap 4 carousel needs this to work. How can I display them and still let the carousel work?

Comment: The left and right captions can be added as before and after pseudo elements of the active slide and default controls of the slider to be transparent and act as click containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Demo :

Full page : https://codepen.io/devanshj/full/MXXdvO/

With code : https://codepen.io/devanshj/pen/MXXdvO

### Explanation :

1. Used [flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/). Because it handles the difficult things for us.
2. By default `.content` is in center. To move content of slides adjacent to selected slide, Added : `translateX(calc( (100vw-100%)/2 + 5vw )*-1)` and `translateX(calc( (100vw-100%)/2 + 5vw ))` to next and prev slides repectively
3. Added an event handler for `flickity.scroll` that adds `marginLeft` proportionately to the amount be which selected slide is moved so that `.content` comes back to the original (center) position finally

PS: I have kept `autoplay` on `video` but it doesn't work. Maybe because of being inside an `iframe`

Comment: Great code, but what about using `<div class="item is-before-selected" aria-selected="false">` element as prev button. I have implemented that and the prev button does not work.

Comment: That won't work because `.item` is not being shifted only `.content` is shifted towards the selected slide. So you'll have to listen click event on `.content` instead of `.item`. Also I feel pretty fine about using seperate prev and next buttons. Also thanks for the appreciation!

Comment: Correction : `.content h1` instead of `.content`

Comment: Does the flickity plugin have *mouse wheel* advancement option?

Comment: No flickity doesn't offer such option... But oviously you can write your own code for such behaviour... They have pretty good api... Check it out via the link in the answer...

Comment: Just saw the prev button not working... It's because `right:0` on both prev and next instead it should be `right: 0` for next and `left: 0` for prev... I'll update the pen soon...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173774/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-devansh-j).

Comment: Does it have multiple, "effects" like *slide*, *fade* and so on?

Comment: Does the plugin have an option for advancing on *mouse scroll*?

Comment: You can check it here : flickity.metafizzy.co Also oviously you can write your own code to implement it

Comment: How can I make the slide transitions smoother? Where is the code responsible with them?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir As far as I know there is no such option available... The only way to do is change the flicity source code.... Also there is no point in asking questions here... Maybe asking a SO question with [flickity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flickity) tag might help you more...

Comment: I am trying to make the slider loop. **[THIS](https://codepen.io/Ajax28/pen/yqaLmr)** is what I have so far. The right caption of the last slide is not fat enough to the right. Help me, please.

Comment: "slider loop" you mean autoplay?

Comment: I mean when on the *last* slide, if you click "Next", the slider goes to the *first* slide.

Comment: Look at **[this page](http://code-love.tk/demos/prop/)** from a small screen (simulate a portrait iPad), go to the *last slide*. You will see: the caption on the right is not far enough to the right.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir You can change the how much next and prev caption is visible by changing `5vw` in css and js. And if you don't want to loop you can set [`wrapAround: false`](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#wraparound) in the flickity options

Answer (score 1):

You can use "flickity" jquery slider for your desired output, see an example below:

```js
$('#full_slider').flickity({
     wrapAround: true,
     on: {
       ready: function() {
           $('.carousel-cell:first-child()').find('video').get(0).play();
       },
       change: function( index ) {
           $('.is-selected').find('video').get(0).play();
       }
   }
  });
```

```css
#full_slider .slide-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#full_slider .slide-content .video-caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transition: all 500ms;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  color: #fff;
}
#full_slider .slide-content .allcases {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: none;
}
#full_slider .slide-content .allcases a {
  color: #fff;
}


#full_slider video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#full_slider h3 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="main-carousel" id="full_slider">
   <div class="carousel-cell is-selected">
    <div class="slide-content">
     <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/koffee.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
     <div class="video-caption">
      <h3 class="capt text-boldest">All about us</h3>
      <p class="allcases">
       <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-cell">
    <div class="slide-content">
     <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/flamenco.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
     <div class="video-caption">
      <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
      <p class="allcases">
       <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-cell">
    <div class="slide-content">
     <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/protest.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
     <div class="video-caption">
      <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Falling in love</h3>
      <p class="allcases">
       <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-cell">
    <div class="slide-content">
     <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
     <div class="video-caption">
      <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Coffe</h3>
      <p class="allcases">
       <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-cell">
    <div class="slide-content">
     <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
     <div class="video-caption">
      <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Dealing with danger</h3>
      <p class="allcases">
       <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Link for the jquery plugin: [flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ads caption of right and left slide as controls of slider you can copy content of captions of left and right slides to left and right controls using jquery see code below i have added some css for display content properly, you can add your css

```js
var slider = $('#full_slider');
var slidesNo = slider.find('.carousel-item').length;

var fullSliderNavigation = function(index) {
  var slide = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index);
  if (slide.is(':first-child')) {
    var slidePrev = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(slidesNo - 1);
  } else {
    var slidePrev = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index - 1);
  }

  if (slide.is(':last-child')) {
    var slideNext = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(0);
  } else {
    var slideNext = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index + 1);
  }

  $('.carousel-item').removeClass('right-slide left-slide');
  slideNext.addClass('right-slide');
  slidePrev.addClass('left-slide');
  
  $('.carousel-control-next').html(slideNext.find('.video-caption').html());
  $('.carousel-control-prev').html(slidePrev.find('.video-caption').html());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  fullSliderNavigation(0);

  $(slider).on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
    var index = $(event.relatedTarget).index();
    fullSliderNavigation(index);
  });
});
```

```css
#full_slider {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
#full_slider .carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#full_slider .carousel-item .video-caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transition: all 500ms;
  transform: translateX(-60px) translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  color: #fff;
}
#full_slider .carousel-item .allcases {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: none;
}
#full_slider .carousel-item .allcases a {
  color: #fff;
}


#full_slider video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
#full_slider h3 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
}


#full_slider .carousel-control h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  display:block;
}

#full_slider .carousel-control p {
  font-size: 14px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div id="full_slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/koffee.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">All about us</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#"><a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/flamenco.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/protest.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Falling in love</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Coffe</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Dealing with danger</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
  
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Copying does not fit my design needs, because I need the captions to slide smoothly *with the slides*.

Comment: An alternative carousel plugin is welcomed. Which would be bast for the job?

Comment: Can you give a practical exemple of the feature you are talking about?

Comment: I have added another answer for you please check that

Answer (score 0):

Added the following styles div

**No changes required in JS**

```
#full_slider .carousel-item.left-slide,
#full_slider .carousel-item.right-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.left-slide {
  z-index: 2;
  left: -90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.active {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.right-slide {
  z-index: 2;
  right: -90%;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.left-slide video,
#full_slider .carousel-item.right-slide video {
  display: none;
}

.carousel-control-next,
.carousel-control-prev {
  z-index: 5;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.left-slide .video-caption {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.left-slide .video-caption,
#full_slider .carousel-item.right-slide .video-caption {
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```js
var slider = $('#full_slider');
var slidesNo = slider.find('.carousel-item').length;

var fullSliderNavigation = function(index) {
  var slide = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index);
  if (slide.is(':first-child')) {
    var slidePrev = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(slidesNo - 1);
  } else {
    var slidePrev = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index - 1);
  }

  if (slide.is(':last-child')) {
    var slideNext = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(0);
  } else {
    var slideNext = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index + 1);
  }

  $('.carousel-item').removeClass('right-slide left-slide');
  slideNext.addClass('right-slide');
  slidePrev.addClass('left-slide');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  fullSliderNavigation(0);

  $(slider).on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
    var index = $(event.relatedTarget).index();
    fullSliderNavigation(index);
  });
});
```

```css
#full_slider {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item .video-caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transition: all 500ms;
  transform: translateX(-60px) translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  color: #fff;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item .allcases {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: none;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item .allcases a {
  color: #fff;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.active,
#full_slider .carousel-item-left,
#full_slider .carousel-item-right {
  display: flex !important;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.active .video-caption {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.active .allcases {
  display: block;
}

#full_slider video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

#full_slider h3 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
}

#full_slider .control {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.left-slide,
#full_slider .carousel-item.right-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.left-slide {
  z-index: 2;
  left: -90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.active {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.right-slide {
  z-index: 2;
  right: -90%;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.left-slide video,
#full_slider .carousel-item.right-slide video {
  display: none;
}

.carousel-control-next,
.carousel-control-prev {
  z-index: 5;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.left-slide .video-caption {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.left-slide .video-caption,
#full_slider .carousel-item.right-slide .video-caption {
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div id="full_slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/koffee.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">All about us</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#"><a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/flamenco.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/protest.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Falling in love</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Coffe</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Dealing with danger</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="control text-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="control text-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var slider = $('#full_slider');
var slidesNo = slider.find('.carousel-item').length;

var fullSliderNavigation = function(index) {
  var slide = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index);
  var slidePrev, slideNext;
  if (slide.is(':first-child')) {
    slidePrev = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(slidesNo - 1);
  } else {
    slidePrev = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index - 1);
  }

  if (slide.is(':last-child')) {
    slideNext = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(0);
  } else {
    slideNext = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index + 1);
  }

  $('.carousel-item').removeClass('right-slide left-slide');
  slideNext.addClass('right-slide');
  slidePrev.addClass('left-slide');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  fullSliderNavigation(0);

  $(slider).on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
    var index = $(event.relatedTarget).index();
    fullSliderNavigation(index);
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-item .video-caption,
.carousel-item .allcases {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-25%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.carousel-item .allcases {
  top: 60%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: translate(-25%, -60%);
}

.carousel-item .video-caption h3 {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.carousel-item video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-item::before {
  content: attr(data-left);
  left: -90%;
  text-align: right;
}

.carousel-item::after {
  content: attr(data-right);
  right: -90%;
  text-align: left;
}

.carousel-item::before,
.carousel-item::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="full_slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-left="Dealing with danger" data-right="Lorem ipsum dolor">
      <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/koffee.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
      <div class="video-caption">
        <h3 class="capt text-boldest">All about us</h3>
      </div>
      <p class="allcases">
        <a class="inherit" href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-left="All about us" data-right="Falling in love">
      <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/flamenco.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
      <div class="video-caption">
        <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
      </div>
      <p class="allcases">
        <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-left="Lorem ipsum dolor" data-right="Coffe">
      <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/protest.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
      <div class="video-caption">
        <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Falling in love</h3>
      </div>
      <p class="allcases">
        <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-left="Falling in love" data-right="Dealing with danger">
      <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
      <div class="video-caption">
        <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Coffe</h3>
      </div>
      <p class="allcases">
        <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-left="Coffe" data-right="All about us">
      <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
      <div class="video-caption">
        <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Dealing with danger</h3>
      </div>
      <p class="allcases">
        <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="control text-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="control text-left"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer. Still, there is a problem: the active slide is *no longer 100% wide*. I am trying to make a carousel like **[THIS ONE](https://antoni.de/)**.

Comment: Please check my updated answer now @RazvanZamfir I have done it as you desired

Comment: I don't want the `.carousel-item.left-slide` and `.carousel-item.right-slide` elements to be squashed (to 10% width). I want the full width and with `display:flex` and I want the carousel to work in this conditions, so that I can rely on *CSS for animations*, like **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dsr6q9nx/)**.

Comment: They are no longer of 10% width. Check my updated answer please

Comment: But the `.carousel-item.left-slide` and `.carousel-item.right-slide` elements are now hidden and, as a consequence, their *captions are hidden too*. :(

Comment: no they are not hidden ! they are visible to me. Please check the snippet again

Comment: Check the second snippet that i added.

Comment: Very nice work but, unfortunately, not what I need. I guess I have to find a slider that does *not* have all the sides but the active one hidden.